# Why is this TensorFlow code so slow?

Tags: python, performance, loops, tensorflow, softmax

I am training a deep neural network multi-class classifier using TensorFlow. The network outputs the linear values from the final layer, which the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` cost function takes as input. However, I don't really care about that linear output per se - I want to know what it looks like when the softmax function is applied to it.

Below the relevant parts of my code:

```
def train_network(x, num_hidden_layers):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x, num_hidden_layers)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        # train the network 
        ...

        # get the network output; x_test is my test data (len=663)
        output = sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x: x_test})

        # get softmax values of output
        for i in range(len(x_test)):
            softm = sess.run(tf.nn.softmax(output[i]))
            pred_class = sess.run(tf.argmax(softm))
            print(pred_class)
            ...
```

Now, that final for-loop in which I calculate the softmax values is extremely slow. Why is that, and how do I do this properly?

Comment: try building tensorflow with correct cpu flags.  also if you hw supports it build with gpu opencl support

Comment: Do not use `for` loop. Put `softm = tf.nn.softmax(prediction)` and `pred_class = tf.argmax(softm)` before `sess`, and call `sess.run([softm, pred_class], feed_dict={x: x_test})`. Otherwise you are calculating test data one by one, which is of course slow.

Comment: Adding to the above comment: You should *never* call `tf.anything` within a session; this creates new ops in the computational graph. Especially within a for-loop: This will create new softmax/argmax ops for *every* test example. This will likely cause execution to become slower and slower as the loop progresses, and eventually it might crash with a memory error.

Comment: @Richard_wth That did it. If you turn your comment into an answer I will mark that as the accepted answer.